# using/importing/injecting spring-managed class into non-spring class

Tags: spring, import

Is there a way to inject/import spring-managed class into a legacy code or non-spring class?

I am working on a spring project, but we have this legacy code that needs access to a spring managed class (specifically a jparepsository implementation class). Is this possible?

Sorry, I am a newbie in the Spring framework. Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always load an application context up in your code.  It's a simple matter of doing something like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/applicationContext.xml");
```

You'll have access to all the beans created there via the getBean() function. This may be sufficient for you. However, you won't be accessing the same context as other parts of your application, you'll have a copy. So if you have stateful beans in your application context the "unmanaged" code won't see the same state.

if you're talking about a web application, then you can use the WebApplicationContextUtils to access the same context as the rest of the web applicatiom.

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
```

Since you have access to the legacy code, what prevents you from rewriting it to be spring managed, or at leas to be ApplicationContextAware?